# How to logrotate 1 MB file?

Tags: cron, logrotate

To rotate logs after the size grows to `1M`, cronjob invokes `logrotate` every 15 mins, as shown below:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /app/syslog-ng/custom/conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf
```

where `syslog-ng-rotate.conf` is

```
/app/syslog-ng/custom/output/all_devices.log {
size 1M
copytruncate
dateext
dateformat -%Y%m%d-%s
rotate 365
sharedscripts
compress
postrotate
     /app/syslog-ng/sbin/syslog-ng-ctl reload
endscript
}
```

---

But the above configuration does not work if file size crosses `1M` within 15 minutes.

How to make sure, that file gets rotated immediately after the file size goes to `1M`?

Comment: Are you saying that logrotate does not work at the next (15-minute-scheduled) cron run? Or that you want it to work between cron runs? You cannot expect logrotate to run when you do not tell it to run..

Comment: @JeffSchaller I want to invoke `logrotate` immediately after file size goes to 1M.. for this knowing the interval  t(say 15 mins) to invoke `logrotate` is not certain....

Comment: Logrotate will only look at the size of your log file when it is executed. With your current configuration, that's every 15 minutes. The log could grow well beyond 1 MB in that time. If you need log rotation at precisely the 1MB mark, you might need to configure that within the application which actually writes to the log file.

Answer (score 1):

logrotate only runs when you tell it to run. If you have a log file that may grow quickly, and you're using cron, I have two suggestions:

1. schedule the cron job more frequently (say, every minute):

   ```
   * * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /app/syslog-ng/custom/conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf
   ```

   so that you have at most 60 seconds for the log file to grow before possibly reaching the size limit.
2. If your log file is still growing too quickly each minute, then run logrotate multiple times within each minute; either one immediately after the other:

   ```
   * * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /app/syslog-ng/custom/conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf; /usr/sbin/logrotate /app/syslog-ng/custom/conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf; /usr/sbin/logrotate /app/syslog-ng/custom/conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf
   ```

   (for example), or:

   ```
   * * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /app/syslog-ng/custom/conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf; sleep 10; /usr/sbin/logrotate /app/syslog-ng/custom/conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf; sleep 10; /usr/sbin/logrotate /app/syslog-ng/custom/conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf
   ```

   ... to give 10 seconds between each call to logrotate. **Note** that you don't want any individual cron job to take more than 60 seconds, or you'll overlap into the next cron job.  Consider wrapping the entire cron job with `timeout`:

   ```
   * * * * * timeout 59 sh -c "/usr/sbin/logrotate /app/syslog-ng/custom/conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf; sleep 10; /usr/sbin/logrotate /app/syslog-ng/custom/conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf; sleep 10; /usr/sbin/logrotate /app/syslog-ng/custom/conf/syslog-ng-rotate.conf"
   ```

You'd have to experiment with the timings and number of calls to logrotate for your environment to keep the log file under control.